# How to extend a mapped knockout viewmodel "on the fly" with additional property?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-web-api, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I'm getting a json object array from my ASP.NET Web API and map it to my knockout viewmodel (`ko.observablearray`). While binding the model to the document I get an "Unable to process binding" error.

This is because the json dto I get from the API doesen't have the `Editable` property defined. How can I add it on the fly while mapping? It should be `false` by default.

Here's the code:

```
var Accessory = function (id, leftOnPatient, reject, amount, patchNumber, additionalInfo, editable) {
  var self = this;

  self.Id = ko.observable(id);
  self.LeftOnPatient = ko.observable(leftOnPatient);
  self.Reject = ko.observable(reject);
  self.Amount = ko.observable(amount);
  self.PatchNumber = ko.observable(patchNumber);
  self.AdditionalInfo = ko.observable(additionalInfo);
  self.Editable = ko.observable(editable); 
}

function MedicinesAndAccessoriesViewModel() {
  var self = this;

  self.Accessories = ko.observableArray([]);
  self.error = ko.observable();

  function getAllAccessories() {
    ajaxHelper(accessoriesUri, 'GET').done(function (data) {
      ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, self.Accessories);     
    });
  };

  getAllAccessories(); 
};

var vm = new MedicinesAndAccessoriesViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(vm, document.getElementById("medicinesAndAccessoriesTab"));
```

HTML:

```html
<ol class="list-group list_of_items padding-top-15" data-bind="foreach: Accessories">
        <li class="list-group-item">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <span data-bind="text: Id, visible: !Editable()"></span> //Here I get the error
....
...
..
.
```

So, how can I define the `Editable(false)` property client side for each `Accessory` loaded from the API? Every other property I get from the dto loaded from the API. Can it be done somehow while mapping?

Answer (score 1):

You're currently not using the `Accessory` constructor function anywhere at all, the word occurs only once at its definition in your snippet...

You need to utilize your mapping definition and tell it to map that part of your json correctly, e.g.:

```
function getAllAccessories() {
    ajaxHelper(accessoriesUri, 'GET').done(function (data) {
        var mappingRules = {
            'accessories': {
                create: function(options) {
                    return new Accessory(
                        options.data.id, 
                        options.data.leftOnPatient, 
                        options.data.reject, 
                        options.data.amount, 
                        options.data.patchNumber, 
                        options.data.additionalInfo, 
                        options.data.editable);
                }
            }
        };

        ko.mapping.fromJS(data, mappingRules, self.Accessories);     
    });
};
```

This should already make sure the `Editable` observable is there. You could try to force it into a boolean with `!!` just in case:

```
self.Editable = ko.observable(!!editable);
```

PS. I recommend making the constructor function slightly less complicated by reducing the number of arguments to one (e.g. `data` or `dto`), so that `return new Accessory(options.data)` will do in the above snippet.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer @Jeroen ! Tried adding this new mapping rule but the `Editable` property is still undefined after loading the data from web api. The accessory dto's loaded from the api don't have the editable property defined. Can't get this to work :/